# Symbolic solution of ODE with matix and vector

Tags: python, r, ode

I'm trying to solve symbolically a system of the two following differential equations either in python or in r:

[image]

I want to find symbolic solutions for `dH/dt=0` and `dV/dt=0`. However, I struggle to convert summations with matrixes and vector into code (python or R). Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any reason to be hopeful that such a symbolic solution exists? `sympy` DE integration is very basic, covers mostly the scalar case and the constant-coefficients linear system case. I don't believe that R is better in that regard. Try a longer developed true CAS like Mathematica or Maple.

Comment: Hello Lutz, the symbolic solution exists and I already know it. However, I would like python or R to give me the solution. Do you think that it would be impossible for me to do such operations on either of these two languages?